# How do I calculate $ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \delta\left(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{i}(t)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, physics

I don't understand how the derivative is calculated in this case:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \delta\left(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{i}(t)\right)=\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x_{i}} \frac{d x_{i}}{d t}+\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial y_{i}} \frac{d y_{i}}{d t}+\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial z_{i}} \frac{d z_{i}}{d t}=-\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x} \frac{d x_{i}}{d t}-\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial y} \frac{d y_{i}}{d t}-\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial z} \frac{d z_{i}}{d t} $$

The multivariable chain rule is -General rule: Vector-valued functions with multiple inputs
The simplest way for writing the chain rule in the general case is to use the total derivative, which is a linear transformation that captures all directional derivatives in a single formula. Consider differentiable functions $ f: \mathbf{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{k} $ and $ g: \mathbf{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbf{R} $ and a point $ \mathbf{a} $ in $ \mathbf{R}^{n} $. Let $ D_{\mathbf{a}} g $ denote the total derivative of $ g $ at $ \mathbf{a} $ and $ D_{g(\mathbf{a})} f $ denote the total derivative of $ f $ at $ g(\mathbf{a}) $. These two derivatives are linear transformations $ \mathbf{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{m} $ and $ \mathbf{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{k} $, respectively, so they can be composed. The chain ru for total derivatives is that their composite is the total derivative of $ f \circ g $ at $ \mathbf{a} $ :
$ D_{\mathrm{a}}(f \circ g)=D_{g(\mathbf{a})} f \circ D_{\mathrm{a}} g, $

First I have to denote that $\delta$ is interpreted as a function in this case.

I would identify $f=\delta$ and the inner function $g(t)=\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{i}(t)=\vec{r}(x(t),y(t),z(t))-\vec{r}_{i}(x(t),y(t),z(t)) $

So $\delta:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R} $ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^3 $, so $\delta \circ g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ and $D_{\mathrm{t}}(\delta \circ g)=D_{g(\mathbf{t})} \delta \circ D_{\mathrm{t}} g = ...$

with $$D_{\mathrm{t}} g= \dot{\vec{r}}-\dot{\vec{r_i}}= \frac{d x}{d t}\hat{e_x}+\frac{d y}{d t}\hat{e_y}+\frac{d z}{d t}\hat{e_z}-\frac{d x_{i}}{d t}\hat{e_x}-\frac{d y_{i}}{d t}\hat{e_y}-\frac{d z_{i}}{d t}\hat{e_z}=(\frac{d x}{d t}-\frac{d x_{i}}{d t})\hat{e_x}+\frac{d x}{d t}-(\frac{d x_{i}}{d t})\hat{e_y}+(\frac{d y}{d t}-\frac{d z_{i}}{d t})\hat{e_z}$$

$$ D_{g(t)} \delta= D \delta(g(t))=??? $$

Edit- more context: Moving charges form a current $ I $, which is described by the atomic current density
$
\vec{J}(\vec{r}, t)=\sum \limits_{i} Q_{i} \vec{v}_{i} \delta\left(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{i}(t)\right)
$
with $ \vec{v}_{i}=\frac{d \vec{r}_{i}}{d t} $ as the velocity of the $ i $-th particle. For charge density and current density, the continuity equation holds:
$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J}=0$ with the atomac charge density $\rho=\sum \limits_{i} Q_{i} \delta\left(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{i}\right)$

Comment: The Dirac delta $\delta$ is not a function but a distribution, so you cannot use the usual chain rule for differentiable functions

Comment: What is $\vec r_i(t)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin This is the location vector of the $i$-th particle

Comment: @stange yes, but it’s from my university script, so there must be some reasoning behind it. I cannot ask the professor currently

Comment: @CherryBlossom1878 I would try to argue via distributional derivatives. Maybe that will lead you somewhere

Comment: As usual, you’re going to need to write down an integral (presumably with respect to $t$) and integrate by parts. Edit your post to give the precise situation in which this arose.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited my post. I hope the situation is clearer now

Comment: So what is the goal? Ordinarily at this point you would integrate over a region $\Omega$ and apply the Divergence Theorem.

Comment: yes that is exactly the next step but I didn't thought that it was necessary to write it in my post

Comment: You are not going to differentiate the delta function directly. Are you telling us that your university textbook is proceeding the way you wrote it in the post? That seems unlikely. It would be a lot easier if you just posted exactly what your textbook has and *then* ask a question.

Comment: You don't need to compute the derivative, as the equation isn't supposed to hold pointwise but rather in the distributional sense. As someone said in another comment, you want to integrate the equation and then perform integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

You typically see those kind of formulas in physics. For example, you can view this as the density of particles for a single particle at position $r_i$. The continuous analogue would be to start with a density $n_0(r)$ and a flow $\phi(r_0,t)$ which gives the new position $r$ at $t$ when starting at $r_0$. Associated with this flow is the velocity field $v(r,t)$ which gives the current velocity of $r$:
$$
\partial_t\phi = v\circ \phi \\
v = \partial_t\phi\circ \phi^{-1}
$$
You can then compute how the density is carried by the flow:
$$
n(r,t) = n_0(\phi^{-1}(r,t))
$$
(the inversion of $\phi$ is only in the spatial part) Assuming differentiability of $n$ and $\phi$, this becomes:
$$
\partial_t n = \partial_rn_0 \cdot \partial_t\phi^{-1}
$$
Since the reverse flow is obtained by switching the sign of the velocity:
$$
\partial_t\phi^{-1} = -v\circ \phi^{-1}
$$
you can rewrite it using the velocity field of the flow:
$$
\partial_t n = -\partial_rn\cdot v
$$
Notice that formula is linear in $n_0$, so it's tempting to decompose it in Dirac deltas. This is how you can interpret your equation. In other terms, it's just way to remember the convective derivative.

Hope this helps.